# Apply Data source steps without data refresh

Tags: powerbi

How do I apply new steps to my data source wihtout needing to refresh the data source when I apply the steps by clicking *Close & Apply*.

[image: CLose & Apply button]

Eg.
I replaced values in an already refreshed data source

[image: Replace value example]

and I click *Close & Apply* only to wait 20 minutes for the data to refresh.
[image: Refresh Data Template]

Using measures to make duplicate columns with the changes I want, is not optimal

Comment: Are you still in development with the pbix? You can limit the rows by only selecting e.g. 1000 rows from the source.

Comment: @NickyvV Yeah was thinking of having 2 separate sources ,one with old data and one with limited data and see if i can match them together and figure out the modified data. will need to do that for each source though.

Comment: You should be able to create a separate "blank" query, set its value to "=existingquery", then do any manipulations on that, leaving the original query intact.

Comment: Is there a way to apply changes step-by-step? I added several data sources and I need to wait for all of them to fetch data, and apply changes. Can I apply changes step-by-step, or source-by-source, or in any way?

Comment: @JakubP if u click cancel on the refresh u can refresh each data source one by one by right-clicking on the data source in the right column then clicking refresh and waiting for it to finish. you can also right click data sources in the _Edit queries_ window and uncheck the _include in refresh_ checkbox to disable auto refresh when the refresh button in the main window is clicked